# Open embedded zipped resource

Tags: c#

I have the same problem where I have one embedded .exe and a data folder with a large number of sub folders within. To handle this I have as well used zip to get the folder inside the resource in VS. But now to my question....

How do I open the zipped folders during runtime? Do I need to open, unzip and save in temp area or can I somehow open I memory and use them from there?

The .exe is created in the temp area, but I was hoping to be able to use this as well onli in memory...

Or could I unzip directly in resource folder?

Great full for answers....

Comment: Do you want just read them? or modify too?

Comment: It's a exe file with folder and sub folders. So I actually don't know if I need to be able to only read or also modify. I shan't to be able to open the program so probably the program needs to save some data in some file inside the folders....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of add the embedded zip file to the temp folder and unzip it.

```
     private string _tempPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP") + @"\";
     private string _zipPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP") + @"\" + @"MyZip.zip";


    /// <summary>
    /// Extracts the contents of a zip file to the 
    /// Temp Folder
    /// </summary>
    private void ExtractZip()
    {
        try
        {                
            //write the resource zip file to the temp directory
            using (Stream stream = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("<Namespace>.Resources.<filename>.zip"))
            {
                using (FileStream bw = new FileStream(_zipPath,FileMode.Create))
                {
                    //read until we reach the end of the file
                    while (stream.Position < stream.Length)
                    {
                        //byte array to hold file bytes
                        byte[] bits = new byte[stream.Length];
                        //read in the bytes
                        stream.Read(bits, 0, (int)stream.Length);
                        //write out the bytes
                        bw.Write(bits, 0, (int)stream.Length);
                    }
                }
                stream.Close();
            }

            //extract the contents of the file we created
            UnzipFile(_zipPath, _tempPath);
             //or
             System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(_zipPath,_tempPath);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //handle the error
        }
    }



    public void UnzipFile(string zipPath, string folderPath)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!File.Exists(zipPath))
            {
                throw new FileNotFoundException();
            }
            if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
            }
            Shell32.Shell objShell = new Shell32.Shell();
            Shell32.Folder destinationFolder = objShell.NameSpace(folderPath);
            Shell32.Folder sourceFile = objShell.NameSpace(zipPath);
            foreach (var file in sourceFile.Items())
            {
                destinationFolder.CopyHere(file, 4 | 16);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //handle error
        }
    }
```

Comment: FYI, the framework has a CopyTo method on streams that allows you to copy the contents of one stream to another.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have added the file to a resource.resx file with the name "ZIP", this one liner does the trick to zip it right to a destination folder:

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(new MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.ZIP), folderPath);
```

Heres a few notes on how it works:

- The static ZipFile class needs System.IO.Compression.
- The MemoryStream class needs System.IO.
- Accessing the resource this way "Properties.Resources.ZIP" is a byte[].  The MemoryStream class has a constructor that takes a byte[] as input, and the  ExtractToDirectory method takes a stream as an input.  As it is a one liner, the MemoryStream drops out of scope as soon as the line is done, so it functions the same as wrapping it up in using statements.

I also had to learn this because I was new to resources, so this may be helpful to some as well:

- The resource name is different than the resources file name, easy to see when you edit a resource.resx file for the first time.
- New resources are not available to Visual studio and won't populate from intellisense typing "Properties.Resources." until you save the resx file.
- To add a resource.resx file to your project in VS2022, press Ctrl+Shift+A or use your favorite UI way to open the Add New Item dialog, and find Resource File:
  [image: Adding a resource file to a project in VS2022]